# Use of private static methods

Tags: php, static, static-methods, private-members

I am trying to work out whether the private static method in the example below should be non-static. It is only concerned with the static properties of the class which leads me to believe it is okay as a static method. However, it is only invoked from a non-static method, which suggests it should be a non-static method too.

I understand when a public method should be static, but not when a private method should be static.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    private static $initialized = false;
    private static $staticProperty1;
    private static $staticProperty2;
    private        $normalProperty1;

    public function __construct($normalProperty)
    {
        $this->normalProperty1 = $normalProperty;
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        self::initialize();
        // Now do some other stuff
    }

    private static function initialize()
    {
        if (!self::$initialized) {
            self::$staticProperty1 = 'Hello';
            self::$staticProperty2 = 'World';
            self::$initialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question. You want to know when a private function should be static.
<strike>It has to be static if you want to call it from another static method. That is because you do not have access to `$this`.</strike>

My previous assumption was not correct. You can also call a non static method from a static function. But you have to consider that you do not have access to the object itself with the variable `$this`. Also it is not possible to access non static object properties.

In your example, in my opinion if you call the method from a non static context anyway, you can make it not static. There is no need for it to be static. But I cannot tell you if this is good practice. Just what I would do.

Comment: Okay thanks. I understand it probably comes down to personal preference in the end, but I like being as semantic as possible with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I do private static method when I want my public static method to call another method.

Comment: Yes I would do the same, but in this case the public method is not static. Would you change the private method to be non-static, even though it is only setting static properties?

Comment: Yes, I would change it to be an instance method, since it was called by an another instance method. There's also no reason for it to be static. Another thing is, since your method initializes static variables for now, it would work, but what if you want to initialize non-static variables, would you want to separate it?

Comment: Okay makes sense. Your point about possibly setting non-static properties in future is a nice way to think about it!